# Query no effect on mockups

Tags: css, responsive

The media query has no effect on the pictures inside my div, what I want is to say if the screen is wider then 1700px, everything needs to stay on the same place and be resized. The content wrapper, the content inside and the mockups do not changing at all.

```css
content-wrapper{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9;
 margin: 2.5% 0 0 8%;
 padding: 1%;
 float: left;
 width: 1100;
}

.content{
 width: 300px;
 margin: 5% 0 0 0;
 float: left;
}

.mockups{
 width: 650;
 margin: 0 0 0 10%;
 float: left;
    height: auto;
}

.badge2{
 float: right;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

/* Responsive Content */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
 .content-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  margin: 2.5% 0 0 8%;
  padding: 1%;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .content{
  width: 30%;
  margin: 5% 0 0 0;
  float: left;
 }

 .mockups{
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 0 0 10%;
  float: left;
     height: auto;
 }

 .badge2{
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please include your HTML

Comment: please add the image you want to use into the HTML

Answer (score 0):

For wider than 1700px use:
`@media only screen and (min-width: 1700px)`

Comment: Why the width is changing but my picture not stretching?